# How can I fix the 'Cannot access memory at address'? using Code Blocks C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm new to C++ and trying to run some previously developed code which was used on Arduino but I now need to run it on a windows PC. I get the above error when I pass *pads to the get_padding function. It stops at pads_in[i] = xxx;

```
    int range = (g_code_length - g_B26_len)-1;
    char* pads[range];
    //char*pads[2];
    //usleep(2000);
    //delay(2);
    char*new_pads = get_padding(*pads,g_B26_len,unit,p);type here

char* Codemanager::get_padding(char* pads_in,int b26codelen ,int uniit , char  clii )
{
    int rot1 = g_brand_id;
    int rot3 = get_index_lookup(clii,0)+1;
    int range = (10 - g_B26_len)-1;
    for(int i = 0; i < range; i ++ ){
    char xxx = caeser_cipher(uniit,rot1,get_char_lookup(i+1,0),rot3);
    pads_in[i] = xxx;
```

I've spent the last 5 hours on this and I need to get it running over the weekend.
I'd appreciate any assistance.
Thanks

I get the following displayed

At C:\C++ Programming\Algo1\Codemanager.cpp:557
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Debugger finished with status 0

Comment: Welcome on SO! It is hard to answer your question with the current information that we got. It would help if you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is the value of `g_code_length`? If it is less than `10` (the value in the `get_padding()` function to calculate the `range`) you will access memory out of bounds of your array which is UB (undefined behavior).

Comment: And btw variable length arrays (VLAs) as your `char* pads[range];` with `range` not being a compile-time-constant are not standard C++. Consider using a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in the code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires showing a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce the crash. See [ask] for more information. Until a [mre] is shown, it is unlikely that anyone will have an answer or an explanation.

Comment: g_code_length = 10, g_B_26_len = 7, resulting in the range being 2

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77851143/edit) your question and add the details there :D

Comment: Enable your compiler warnings.  Fix the problems that those warnings are calling out.  A [mcve] would go a long way to help us help you.

Comment: As mentioned, I'm new to C++ (as in from today) and struggling to grasp it. I will try to get a minimal reproducible example but that will take me some time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
char* pads[range];
```

This creates an array of `char*` with the size `range`. Note that [VLAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) are not part of the C++ standard and even if your compiler supports them via an extension, you should not make use of them since you will probably have trouble compiling the exact same code with different compilers.

`pads` now looks like this (the addresses are made up, there is no way of knowing their values):

```
   [0]      [1]
+--------+--------+
| 0xDEAD | 0xBEEF |
+--------+--------+
  char*    char*
```

Both elements in `pads` are of type `char*`, but there is no value assigned to them. This means that both elements have an indeterminate value and are not pointing to some valid memory address, probably an address which your process does not own. I used some hexadecimal numbers for illustration purposes.

Applying the dereference operator `*` on `pads` has the same effect as `pads[0]` which is the first element in `pads`, which is still the uninitialized `char*` `0xDEAD`. You now pass this pointer to `get_padding()` as `char* pads_in`. There you subscript into it and assign some values via `pads_in[i] = xxx;`. This means that you try to assign a value to an indeterminate location, which is UB (undefined behavior). Now everything could happen. One possibilty is the segmentation fault you experienced.

---

Your problem can be reduced to this simple example:

```
void accessPointer(char* ptr) {
    ptr[0] = 'z';
}

int main() {

    char* uninitialized[2];
    accessPointer(*uninitialized);
    
    char x{ 'x' }, y{ 'y' };
    char* valid[2] = { &x, &y };
    accessPointer(*valid);

    return 0;
}
```

Which results in the following warnings (when using `-Wall -Wextra` compiler flags):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:8:22: warning: 'uninitialized' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
    8 |         accessPointer(*uninitialized);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:7:15: note: 'uninitialized' declared here
    7 |         char* uninitialized[2];
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This crashed with a SIGSEGV, too ([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/9YcM6W7YT)).

Comment: Thank you Joel for this thorough explanation. I know you mentioned to use std::vector instead but I'm already on a huge learning curve to get this program running. Is there a way to create a global array and have each function access it to read and write to it?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve but learncpp.com has an [introduction](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-global-variables/) to global variables. This and the following articles might help you.